# Way to disable SSL redirects in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, devise

I have a Rails 6 app. I have an internal version that is in production, but I can't use an SSL cert with it.

I've tried to turn off SSL redirection with:

```
config.ssl_options = { redirect: false, secure_cookies: false, hsts: false }
```

in config/environment/production.rb

I'm using the standard Devise. The login page is correctly served over http://. When I sign in, however, the page is redirected to an https:// version.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Did you set `config.force_ssl = false` in your environment config?

Comment: @spickermann, yes, I have  `config.force_ssl = false` in the same production.rb

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with the same problem, until I found this section in `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
  # Assume all access to the app is happening through a SSL-terminating reverse proxy.
  # Can be used together with config.force_ssl for Strict-Transport-Security and secure cookies.
  config.assume_ssl = true
```

The line was originally commented out and once I uncommented it the redirect stopped. Whether `config.force_ssl` is true or false doesn't seem to matter.

I'm using Rails 7.1.1, by the way.